# Spring Boot with Spring JPA + Selenium error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, selenium-webdriver, selenium-java

I am using Spring boot 3.1.5. This project usa this dependencies:

```
<dependency>            
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>         
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>       </dependency>


<dependency>            
<groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>  
<artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>      
</dependency>
```

Now, this works but I am getting this warning:

`` Unable to find version of CDP to use for . You may need to include a dependency on a specific version of the CDP using something similar to `org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-devtools-v86:4.8.3` where the version ("v86") matches the version of the chromium-based browser you're using and the version number of the artifact is the same as Selenium's. ``

I decide update my managed selenium java version (by default it's using 4.8.3) for the latest version (4.15.0) overriding the seleneium.version property in my pom.xml:

```
<selenium.version\>4.15.0</selenium.version\>
```

When I set this property, I can see that my project uses the latest selenium library but I am getting this error:

It's like this updated dependency brokes my database configuration. Whats the problem with this? Maybe is not compatible with spring data or other library?

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'batchDataSourceInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/batch/BatchAutoConfiguration$DataSourceInitializerConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BatchDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer]: Factory method 'batchDataSourceInitializer' threw exception with message: Failed to determine DatabaseDriver
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:654) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:642) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1332) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1162) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1166) ~[spring-context-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:940) ~[spring-context-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:616) ~[spring-context-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:738) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:440) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at com.myapplication.myapplicationApplication.main(myapplicationApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BatchDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer]: Factory method 'batchDataSourceInitializer' threw exception with message: Failed to determine DatabaseDriver
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:171) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:650) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to determine DatabaseDriver
    at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.init.PlatformPlaceholderDatabaseDriverResolver.getDatabaseDriver(PlatformPlaceholderDatabaseDriverResolver.java:144) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.init.PlatformPlaceholderDatabaseDriverResolver.determinePlatform(PlatformPlaceholderDatabaseDriverResolver.java:132) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.init.PlatformPlaceholderDatabaseDriverResolver.lambda$resolveAll$0(PlatformPlaceholderDatabaseDriverResolver.java:97) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.init.PlatformPlaceholderDatabaseDriverResolver.resolveAll(PlatformPlaceholderDatabaseDriverResolver.java:122) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.init.PlatformPlaceholderDatabaseDriverResolver.resolveAll(PlatformPlaceholderDatabaseDriverResolver.java:97) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BatchDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer.resolveSchemaLocations(BatchDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer.java:83) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BatchDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer.getSettings(BatchDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer.java:72) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BatchDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer.<init>(BatchDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer.java:47) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BatchAutoConfiguration$DataSourceInitializerConfiguration.batchDataSourceInitializer(BatchAutoConfiguration.java:174) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:139) ~[spring-beans-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Could not get Connection for extracting meta-data
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:362) ~[spring-jdbc-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.init.PlatformPlaceholderDatabaseDriverResolver.getDatabaseDriver(PlatformPlaceholderDatabaseDriverResolver.java:140) ~[spring-boot-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    ... 39 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:87) ~[spring-jdbc-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:336) ~[spring-jdbc-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    ... 40 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 'url' not set
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:76) ~[spring-core-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:142) ~[spring-jdbc-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:205) ~[spring-jdbc-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:169) ~[spring-jdbc-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:160) ~[spring-jdbc-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:118) ~[spring-jdbc-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:81) ~[spring-jdbc-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    ... 41 common frames omitted
```